# call an interval() immediately without distoring its intervals

Tags: angular, angular5

I have an Observable.interval(600000) which runs ever 10 minutes. A component is subscribed to it and it works well. But what I want is, is there away to have it run automatically when the app loads without affecting its interval time of 600000miliseconds?

Note: code is heavily shortened to make a point.

```
@Injectable()
export class CalculateService {
  result: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(

  ) {


    Observable.interval(600000)
      .subscribe((data) => {
         this.result.next(true);


      });

  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? That observable works kind of "automatically" and fires after the interval has passed

Comment: Yes, I get that @molamk. Currently, a specific component is subscribed to it and it starts working after 6 minute automatically. But say from a button or something, I want to run the logic behind it immediately (as tho the interval is set to 0).

Comment: sorry..my english is bad but I was asking if there is away to tell the Observable to run 'right now' without waiting for the interval to pass from specific areas but then continue working on as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [startWith](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/startwith.html) operator, and it will emit the first value to your observable.

So if you want it to start right away, give it a value of 0, like `startWith(0)`.
In your example it looks like this

```
Observable.interval(600000)
      .subscribe((data) => {
         this.result.next(true);
}).startWith(0);
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it.

Comment: Glad it was of help!

Comment: Hey @molamk not really part of my issue but just curious: while it waits for the interval to be reached, what if i want to order it to fire at any given time from a click element? Would storing the Observable in an observable variable then call its startWith() work --it seems to generate errors. How would that be implemented?

Comment: it's probably better to separate different event sources. Subscribe your `this.result` to another Observable which would be listening to some clicks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Observable.timer(0, 600_000).subscribe etc.
This will start right away and emit a value every ten minutes like you wanted.